# from django.allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.allauth'

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have installed django-allauth with `docker-compose exec web pipenv install django-allauth`, but I recieve an erro `from django.allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.allauth'`, when I use `docker-compose exec web python manage.py makemigrations`. Thaks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you should replace 
`from django.allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter`
with 
`from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter`

django.allauth means that you are looking for module *allauth* inside Django. But *allauth* is an independent Python module inside Python site-packages. So just call it without `Django.` prepended.